Is there a way to restart the Web Audio API oscillator from the beginning each time a button is clicked?
I am in the process of building a kick drum synthesizer through the use of Web Audio API. I have managed my button to run a function which generates a sine wave with both pitch and gain sweep, yet the button seems to work only once, and when clicked again, it doesn't play the sound from the beginning.
const audioCtx = new AudioContext(); // Initiate Audio Context
const osc = audioCtx.createOscillator(); // Create An Oscillator
const volume = audioCtx.createGain(); // Create A Gain



osc.type = "sine"; // Set the type of the waveform
osc.frequency.value = 440; // Set the frequency value of the oscillator

osc.start(); // Start playing the oscillator
osc.connect(volume); // Set the destination of the oscillator  


function generateKick() {
   volume.gain.value = 1;
   osc.frequency.setTargetAtTime(22, 0, 0.1)
   volume.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime, 0.1);
   volume.connect(audioCtx.destination);
   
}

How can I modify my function in such a way that each time the button is clicked it starts from the beginning and gives the same sound?
JSFiddle
I tried putting the osc.start() function inside my own function yet this doesn't work since the .start() function cannot be called more than once.

I'm not a Web Audio expert, but using setValueAtTime to reset the volume and frequency before each setTargetAtTime seems to do the trick (I also put volume.connect outside the function, so it's executed only once):
const audioCtx = new AudioContext(); // Initiate Audio Context
const osc = audioCtx.createOscillator(); // Create An Oscillator
const volume = audioCtx.createGain(); // Create A Gain

osc.type = "sine"; // Set the type of the waveform
osc.frequency.value = 440; // Set the frequency value of the oscillator

osc.start(); // Start playing the oscillator
osc.connect(volume); // Set the destination of the oscillator  

volume.gain.value = 0;
volume.connect(audioCtx.destination);

function generateKick() {
   volume.gain.setValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime);
   volume.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime, 0.1);

   osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime);
   osc.frequency.setTargetAtTime(22, audioCtx.currentTime, 0.1);
}

